# Create user object or save directly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, web-development-server

I am working on a pet project that lets user create account and post ads of things they wanna sell. The tech is, express/nodejs, handblebars, mongoose/mongodb. I am relatively new to JS and learning it as I am working on this project.

To get user's info for sign up I pick form data from HTML5 and send to my route /signup. Where I

```
 var usertoadd = {

                        username: req.body.username,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: req.body.password,
                        country: req.body.country


                    };

                    var newuser = new User(usertoadd);
                    newuser.save(function (err, newuser) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);

                        }
                        req.session.user = newuser;
                        req.session.loggedIn = true;
                        req.session.save();
```

Everything works but I have a feeling I am doing something wrong. Maybe I need constructor function to create instance of `usertoadd` for every new user that my form sends? But I don't understand why would I do that if this works fine. I am definitely not understanding something conceptual here but what?

If I had a constructor function that created user and then added them like so

```
function newuser({username, pass}){

    this.username = username;
    this.pass = pass;


}


var usercomingfromform = {username: "mesam", pass: "pass"}
var usertoadd = new newuser(usercomingfromform);
```

Comment: `usertoadd` is just an Object containing a bunch of strings. Creating a new `User` instance based on that and saving it will add the info to the database. Not sure what you think is missing here. You cannot "save things directly in JavaScript", that's what you need the database for in the first place. (Because even if you kept the user information in memory by storing it in a global variable or something, it would be gone as soon as you had to restart your server)

Comment: If I wrote something like this                                                                                `function newuser({username, pass}){

 this.username = username;
 this.pass = pass;


}


var usercomingfromform = {username: "mesam", pass: "pass"}
var usertoadd = new newuser(usercomingfromform);`

Comment: ...but *why*? What's the goal here? You are storing the user in the database. What more do you need? If they try to log in, you run the entered login data against the database, and if there's a match, there's your returned user.

Comment: @ChrisG I don't know what is wrong with me. If I successfully write a code that functions I get a feeling I got it right by chance and I might be doing something poorly. Is that some kind of syndrome?

Comment: Nah, you're not the only one for sure :) Writing server-side code that deals with a bunch of clients can be pretty daunting to wrap your mind around.